# neo4j: represent object property instead of relationship in links between objects

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to use neo4j to represent networks, in order to make nice graphics like this one:
[image]

Here is the code used so far:

```
CREATE (router1:Router {name:'router1', defaultgw:'192.168.123.1'})
CREATE (network1:Network {name:'network1', cidr:'192.168.123.0/24'})
CREATE (server1:Server {hostname:'server1', ip:'192.168.123.7'})
CREATE (server2:Server {hostname:'server2', ip:'192.168.123.9'})
CREATE
(router1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(network1),
(network1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(server1),
(network1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {}]->(server2) 
WITH router1 AS r
  MATCH (r)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(n)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(s) RETURN r,n,s
;
```

Is there a way to represent the subnet used between router and network, and the ip of the server on the link between servers and related network, instead of the appropriate but meaningless `CONNECTED_TO` ?

I have tried to define relationships as:

```
CREATE (router1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {'192.168.123.0/24'}]->(network1)
or
CREATE (router1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {network1.cidr}]->(network1)
```

with no success. Is it even possible ?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

Every property needs a name. For example, `cidr`:

```
CREATE (router1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {cidr: '192.168.123.0/24'}]->(network1)
```

Here is a complete query:

```
CREATE (router1:Router {name:'router1', defaultgw:'192.168.123.1'})
CREATE (network1:Network {name:'network1', cidr:'192.168.123.0/24'})
CREATE (server1:Server {hostname:'server1', ip:'192.168.123.7'})
CREATE (server2:Server {hostname:'server2', ip:'192.168.123.9'})
CREATE
  (router1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {cidr: '192.168.123.0/24'}]->(network1),
  (network1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {ip:'192.168.123.7'}]->(server1),
  (network1)-[:CONNECTED_TO {ip:'192.168.123.9'}]->(server2) 
WITH router1 AS r
  MATCH (r)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(n)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(s) RETURN r,n,s
;
```

*But adding this property to the relationship would cause storage of the property in two places -- which may be wasteful, and if the property value needed to change that would require extra effort to perform the update in multiple places. I would advise putting the property in only one place, with the decision depending on the needs of all your use cases.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not seem to work ; I have used this ``WITH gw_project_router AS g
MATCH p=(g)-[:CONNECTED_TO *]->(x)
WHERE NOT (x)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->()
RETURN p;`` as query

Comment: See my edited answer for the complete query. It works for me.

Comment: You're right: it works. Maybe the fact I have been adding relationships with and without properties didn't let me chose for the whole graph which property I wanted to display. Many thanks!